# Is there a way in my custom classloader to attach my classloader to the class while I delegate to super createing it?

Tags: java, classloader

I have this stack trace which is the FIRST time this class is loaded(I have a condition on the breakpoint for this class)....

[image]

The CompilingClassLoader is mine(ie. this one https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/core/runtimecompile/src/main/java/org/webpieces/compiler/impl/CompilingClassloader.java )

I want this class that is being loaded in a way that it is plugin.getClass.getClassLoader is returning the CompilingClassLoader.  Instead, it's classloader is AppClassLoader

This is causing many issues for plugin developers in that currently the workaround is a Thread context classloader.  Is there a way to claim the compiling classloader loaded it but delegate to the super classloader?

The CRITICAL line is line 111 in the link above by the way.  I want that line to use the super class to create the Class for me BUT I want it to look like I created the Class.  ie. the Class returned should return 'my' classloader when clazz.getClassLoader() is called.  this then fixes a ton of issues.

**EDIT---------------------------------------**

After further investigation.  The CompilingClassLoader is very very tricky.  You have these types of classes

1. Standard java.lang classes
2. webpieces startup classes
3. the applications compile on demand classes
4. webpieces plugin classes that sit below application classes and above them
5. libraries that sit below application classes AND above them

For #1, once I hit main, many of these like java.lang.Object are loaded by app classloader so this must remain true always so that you don't get the dreaded casting X to X yields ClassCastException

For #2, most of these are loaded by app classloader on startup as well

For #3, this is code that we compile OR recompile.  To recompile, we throw away the CompilingClassLoader and recreate another one BUT cache bytes of all previously compiled classes that have not changed.

For #4 & #5, this is where it gets really really tricky!!!  We have a ProdServerMeta (an application compiled class) that refers to plugins in webpieces and those plugins then sometimes load other application classes that need to compile on changes.  Currently, we inject hibernate with the compiling classloader to avoid an issue.

The more I think about this, hibernate classes are loaded by app classloader right now because we return null when we can't compile a class delegating to the parent.

Now, I ran into these situations with CompilingClassLoader which is very hard to simplify into a classloader like Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling's classloader below!  Mainly because defineClass seems to be critical and missing in that example (and like what Olivier says below is very important).

Anyways, I ran into these things with trying the classloader below

- loading of java.lang.* caused a SecurityException so I had to delegate that
- After solving that, I ran into ClassCastException from SAXParserFactoryImpl to SAXParserFactoryImpl when slf4j tries to load configuration

This 2nd one makes total senses since Server.main creates a Logger and then every other class that creates a Logger creates it in a CompilingClassLoader.  This leads me to the situation that

**I cannot load ANYTHING that is loaded before the loading of the application**

Next, being a webserver for customers, I also can't tell what is referenced in pre-app load vs. after app load.

I am coming to the conclusion that there is not a solution since as a developer writes code, I throw away the previous classloader and many classes have to continue to exist like Logger which is referenced by AppClassLoader on startup.

Of course, if I boot up with a CompilingClassLoader, I might stand a better chance in that I could 'try' to load everything perhaps but java.lang, BUT then I still run into the issue of some code after server bootup willl always be referenced by the FIRST CompilingClassLoader while later code on recompile will point to a new CompilingClassLoader.

I think the only solution then is for plugins to have to use the ContextClassLoader the more I think through this situation and that Olivier below is correct in it's not possible.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: You can try to use the parent to call `getResourceAsStream`. But I would advice against that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn why advise against it?  I could cache globally I hope in some static var so as the CompilingClassLoader keeps swapping out, I am not recreating those but just looking them up.  What issues would getResourceAsStream have?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778660/my-custom-java-classloader-loads-a-class-but-clazz-getclassloader-is-myclassl).

Comment: @Olivier Can you expand on the answer in that post?  I am confused how to make sure defineClass is called in my classloader.  Currently, I return null on line 154 in the above source delegating to parent.  Instead of returning null, how would I call into parent to get bytes and call define class.  Also on line 110, I call super.loadClass() so I think I need a fix for that, but not sure how?  You can post an answer here and I can just assing the bounty to you as it gets me at least close to solving this.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is "you can't".

Comment: Could you tell why do you need this? I didn't run your code, but I expect that all classes from the application should return your class loader. The method `defineClass` is responsible for that. Did you check, which classes get loaded with the platform class loader? 
I made a toy example of a class loader, and found that the parent loader loads `java.lang.System`, `java.lang.String`, etc. I do doubt that you want those classes to be loaded by your class loader.

Comment: @PakUula. When customers use webpieces, all org.webpieces code is loaded by parent classloader as well including the hibernate plugin.  so compiling classloader loads customers Meta.java -> customer has a webpieces plugin in Meta -> we ask compiling classloader bug that is not a class we compile on-demand and it's delegated to parent much like java.lang.String BUT THEN hibernate tries to load CustomerDbo.java which is the customers using the classloader hibernate was in.  Because of this, we have to seet a context classloader on hibernate instead to work around the issue.

Comment: @PakUula Also, hibernate is just ONE use case that came up.  These cases keep coming up so IF ALL classes went through compiling classloader, we would not have to keep coaching our users as everything would 'just work' which is what we would prefer.  (ie. it's an expensive support cost right now that pops up once in a while)

Comment: @PakUula I wonder if I just have to define all classes in my classloader instead of delegating to parent so they all 'look' loaded by me even though I only did that so the classloader on each class sticks with compiling classloader.  I was tempted to add to cmd line but that's annoying for users in microservices that have to keep modifying the start cmd line args for each server.

Answer (score 1):

Classloaders load classes from their parent class loaders first. You should be able to work around this by simply not setting a parent classloader for the classloader, and delegate the call for `loadClass` yourself.

A working example:

```java
public class SomeClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Class loader for class: " + getClass().getClassLoader());
        System.out.println("Class loader for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        System.out.println("Class loader for transitive dependency: " + SomeDependency.class.getClassLoader());
    }

}
```

A transitive dependency:

```java
public class SomeDependency {}
```

Test and classloader:

```java
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Test {

    public static class CustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

        ClassLoader delegate;

        public CustomClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
            super(urls, null);
            delegate = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            try {
                return super.loadClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                return delegate.loadClass(name);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        URL location = SomeClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        CustomClassLoader customClassLoader = new CustomClassLoader(new URL[] { location }, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(customClassLoader);
        Class<?> aClass = customClassLoader.loadClass("com.pkg.SomeClass");
        Runnable runnable = (Runnable) aClass.newInstance();
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Class loader for class: com.pkg.Test$CustomClassLoader@4e50df2e
Class loader for thread: com.pkg.Test$CustomClassLoader@4e50df2e
Class loader for transitive dependency: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
```

Seems to do precisely what you want :)

Comment: @Jan-Wilem Gmelig. The transitive dependency I also want to be loaded by Test$CustomClassLoader though (ie. in my case CompilingClassLoader == your CustomerClassloader).  Basicallly, I want all transitive children and grandchildren and their children to ALL have grandchild.getclass.getClassLoader() == CompilingClassLoader 'not' Launcher$AppClassLoader.  It was very close though!!!  Marking up the answer just for trying.

Comment: btw @jan-Wilem, throwing exceptions I remember is expensive (unless you override fillInStackTrace to do nothing) and doing it in a classloader seems like a major major slowdown as well in classloading.

Comment: If the dependency class is also available at any of the the URLs of the URLClassloader, it will load through the custom classloader as well.

Comment: My point of the dependency was that its still able to look up unavailable classes in the delegate classloader, not that you have to. The more classes that will be available in the custom classloader, the lesser exceptions should be a concern

Comment: Odd on jdk11.0.5, it is printing CustomClassLoader 3 times.  What jdk are you running on?  The bounty expires in 2 hours so I am just going to award to you.  I may comment here with a branch new post and bounty that one as well later.  I really need to try to fix this at some point so I have to dig deep and understand more.  Let me know your jdk version because I copied your code verbatim and it doesn't work like it does for you.  (I might be using open jdk 11 as well..not sure there yet)

Comment: Its supposed to print `CustomClassLoader` if the `SomeDependency` class is resolvable through  the `CustomClassLoader`.  In my initial test I moved  `SomeDependency` to a separate package not contained by the `location` URL, as a means to demonstrate that classes that could not be loaded can still be resolved to through the "parent" (now delegate) classloader.

This is the desired behaviour you want right? Whatever class is resolvable through the URLs for `CustomClassLoader` , will always be loaded through that classloader.

Comment: I might have tested on either JDK 8 or 11, I don't remember. Certainly willing to retest on JDK 11 for sure. But your observation is pretty logical to me still. We just have to figure out what exactly you want :)

Comment: Do you have a github repo you can commit that too?  I moved the class to another package to reproduce not because I want that behavior but to 'understand' more.  I edited my post with a ton of detail on why I now think it is not possible.  I will have to stick with ThreadContextClassLoader which 99% of the time is working as desired.  Thanks for all the help, and if you have any other insights, please do share.  It's been interesting learning even more detail in this subject.

Comment: perhaps I should rename it to recompiling classloader ;).  After all, it actually recompiles any time the developer makes changes so that you don't have to restart the webpieces server.    (or course it is just a library that I guess can be plugged into any app to allow no server reboots while you code).