# My custom java ClassLoader loads a class, but clazz.getClassLoader() is myClassLoader.getParent(), not myClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

I have a classloader, which looks like this:

```
@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if(isExcluded(name)) return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
    //  irrelevant... it always returns above
    InputStream s = getResourceAsStream(name.replace('.', '/') + ".class");
    if(s == null) throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
    ClassReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new ClassReader(s);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(Opcodes.ASM4);
    ClassVisitor v = new RemappingClassAdapter(writer, remapper);

    reader.accept(v, 0);

    byte[] bytes = writer.toByteArray();
    Class<?> c = defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    if(resolve) {
        resolveClass(c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then I do

```
MyClassLoader loader = new MyClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
Class<?> c = loader.loadClass(className, true); // also tried false, and loader.loadClass(className)
c.getClassLoader(); // AppClassLoader instead of MyClassLoader, why?
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
return m.invoke(c.newInstance());
```

Shouldn't a class which gets loaded by a classloader, have it's classloader be that classloader? The reason I want this is so that any class which is referenced by this class I am loading (`className`), I want it to get loaded by MyClassLoader too. If thats not how anything works, how does it work? And how do I do what I want to do?

Comment: @user I don't want my classloader to be the default. I want classes loaded with my classloader to actually be loaded with my classloader because apparantly they aren't, according to clazz.getClassLoader()

Comment: I've never dealt with custom ClassLoaders myself, but I will note that the javadoc for ClassLoaders includes this tidbit:  "When requested to find a class or resource, a ClassLoader instance will usually delegate the search for the class or resource to its parent class loader before attempting to find the class or resource itself."

Comment: @Powerlord Right, but then when the parent finds it, I'm pretty sure the classloader itself *links* it, or i may be wrong, thats why I'm asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class loader delegates to its parent, the class loader associated with the loaded class (returned by `Class.getClassLoader()`) is the parent loader. That's because the parent loader is the one that called `defineClass()`.

`defineClass()` is the key method; it calls some native code in the JVM that creates the class and associates it to its class loader.

Comment: Alright! I didn't know that was the case; I thought the classloader calling `resolveClass(c)` is what associates it.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that I have not worked with custom ClassLoader but as I understand it at the level of these ClassLoader objects is that they are related to each other with a parent / child relationship.
This implies that when a ClassLoader is going to load a class, it first asks its parent ClassLoader if it has it available, in this case it loads it. In the event that the parent ClassLoader cannot load it, delegate the request to the next parent until reaching the BootStrapClassLoader. If none of the parent ClassLoader can load the class, the current class loader will try to load it from its available routes. Failure to find it will result in a ClassNotFoundException.

I hope these links can help you: [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders)
[javaworld](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html)

Comment: That doesn't matter. First of all, it depends on the implementation (I think), and second, even if thats true, the resulting class should have `myClass.getClassLoader() == myClassLoader` but it's not. That's the problem here. And if that expression isn't true, it means that other classes loaded by `myClass` will not go through `myClassLoader`.

Comment: @FireCubez The "real" class loader (returned by `getClassLoader()`) is the one that called `defineClass()`.

Comment: @Olivier oh? So, how would I use the parent class to "locate" the class, but have its classloader be mine? If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @FireCubez You can't. You must call `defineClass()` yourself if you want to be the class loader associated with the class.

Comment: @Olivier Okay then.

Comment: @Olivier Could you post an answer so I can accept it?